# Printf() before line causing segmentation fault does not execute

Tags: c, gcc

When a segmentation fault occurs, the printf() before it does not execute.

```
main()
{
 printf( "something" );
 statement;  //this statement causes a segmentation fault
}
```

In the situation above, why does the printf() not execute?

So do I need to use valgrind in such a case(which prints all printf() before the faulty statement).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An output stream can fail to be output before a program crash but you can force the bytes to be output by flushing them with fflush().

I usually do it with something like this:

```
if (trace) { fflush(stdout); }
```

Comment: "trace" is anything special ..?? or u have just used to detect segmention fault.?

Comment: @Mr.32 -- I took his ```trace``` to be a variable he set up during init, maybe from a command-line option.

Comment: Alternately, `fprintf` to `stderr`.

Comment: @DavidThornley No, while sending to stderr is a nice thing to do, it would still get caught up and _possibly_ not sent out; what flush does is tell the system to flush the pending writes - get em done! So, fprintf to stderr would have the same behavior as the previous call.

Comment: `stderr` is unbuffered by default, even if redirected to a file.  It never needs manual flushing after any IO call on it.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure you include a newline `"\n"` in your printf statement. Normally, at least in UNIX systems, `stdout` is line-buffered so newline character makes the line to appear immediately. You probably omitted `"\n"` (or your output is not flushed for other reason) and that's why you can't see the printed string.

Another option is to flush the output yourself using `fflush(stdout)` after calling `printf`.

Comment: it does for line buffered output

Comment: @Mr.32 -- If you redirect your output to a file, the line-buffering trick won't work.  Just use fflush() -- it's portable and consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Output via `printf()` and any other standard I/O function is buffered in the standard C library.

You need to call `fflush()` to ensure the output is sent to the tty before your program crashes.

Comment: Interesting uncommented -1, somebody.